# How to verify text everytime after posting with Selenium WebDriver using java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have a comment page where people can write a comment in text field and post the comment by clicking on submit button.Like Facebook comment.After posting the comment, I have verified that comment.Now I want to add 2nd comment and also want to verify this 2nd comment.So is there any way to verify the text/comment every time after posting?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a loop? Your scope is not really clear. Do you want to do this as part of your automation testing with a set of test data (like a list of comments)?

Comment: How have you posted comment? By using loop? Please provide the snippet of code?

Comment: If you add comment by using loop, you can also verify/assert inside the loop. So you don't need to verify every time separately.

Comment: Yes, I used loop.Here is my posting comment code:

Comment: for(int i =0; i<2; i++){
driver.findElement(By.name("comment_body[und][0][value]")).sendKeys("test comment1");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='commnet_form_submit_handler(); return false;']")).click();
}
assertEquals("test comment1", driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='field-item even'][6]")).getText()); 
Now I want to add another comment(test comment2 for example) using loop and also want to verify that test comment2 without manually changing anything in the code.So how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
protected boolean isTextPresent(String text){
        try{
            boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains(text);
            return b;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

String s[] = {"test comment1", "test comment2"};
        for(int i =0; i<s.length; i++){
            driver.findElement(By.name("comment_body[und][0][value]")).sendKeys(s[i]);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='commnet_form_submit_handler(); return false;']")).click();
            assertTrue(isTextPresent(s[i]));
        }
```